# Convolutional neural network block notation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, image-classification, convolution

The paper by [He et al. "Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) illustrates their residual network in Figure 3 as follows:

[image]

I am not a neural network expert, so could somebody please explain to me what the highlighted notation above "3x3 conv, 256, /2" means? The first part is clear (convolutional neural network with a 3x3 pixel window), but what is the "256" and the "/2"?

Comment: 256 is the number of filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3x3 conv, 256, /2

stands for:

- 3x3 Kernel
- 256 filters
- a stride of 2 halving the spatial dimensions

The latter is explained on page 3 where the authors state

> (ii) if the feature map size is halved, the number of filters is doubled so as to preserve the time complexity per layer. We perform downsampling directly by
>   convolutional layers that have a stride of 2.

This means ResNet does, except for the beginning and end of the network, not use pooling layers to reduce spatial dimensions but conv. layers.

Also, table 1 shows what is happening:

[image: Table 1]

The part you have highlighted in your screenshot is the transition from conv3_x to the conv4_x layer of the 34-layer network. As you can see in the table the output size is reduced from 28x28 to 14x14 (that is what `/2` does) while the filters are doubled from 128 to 256.